Why can this system be written in terms of a Hamiltonian?

How is $\dot{x}$ of (4.1) represented by $\dot{x}$ of (4.4)?
The given hamiltonian is $H_{eff} = T(k,x) + U(x,\mu)$ where $T(k,x) := -\frac{2}{\mu^{2}}\sinh(\mu)\tanh(\mu)\cos(k)$. The corresponding derivative with respect to $k$ is:
$$\frac{d}{dk}T(k,x) = \frac{2}{\mu^{2}}\sinh(\mu)\tanh(\mu)\sin(k)$$
So we are missing the sum of $(4.1)$. What am I missing?
Source: https://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=tmf&paperid=5188&option_lang=eng

From what seems from the text, when you analyze the center of mass, the terms that you mentioned become a constant.

Try showing that the $\partial_k \dot x = - \partial_x \dot k$. This will imply that $(\dot x, -\dot k)$ is a gradient.
